# 12.04 & 11.10 macbook pro issues. Trackpad and Mouse aren't working. Can't login or boot from cd

Tags: 11.04, 12.04, wireless, mouse, macbook

I just updated my macbook to 12.04 LTS and upon install my wi-fi wasn't working or even showing up for that matter. I then downgraded to 11.10 via booting from an install disc. Upon downgrading to 11.10 I had the wifi problem yet again, along with my mouse not working. ( a USB one helped me )

I then restarted the system and wifi and the mouse problems were temporarily fixed. I then installed a few sources & apple drivers via terminal. I rebooted so these could take effect and my computer now won't respond to mouse or even keyboard actions. Even when plugging in a USB mouse or keyboard nothing works.

I can't boot from CD holding C at startup, and can't get into the boot options with shift either. I also have tried Control Alt F1 with no luck.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when booting from CD. Then I got it solved by holding the "option/alt" key and it shows whether to boot from CD. Hope it helps. CD was showing up as windows cd for me eventhough it was Linux Mint CD.